# pthreads wait and signal doubts linux

Tags: pthreads, signals, wait

Before pthread wait we lock using a mutex so that some other code might not try to change the condition variable. wait then unlocks the mutex and waits for the signal.

Say, in some other thread i had locked the same mutex and after that, i had used 'signal'. and then unlock thread.
when signal is done, the waiting thread wakes up and aquires the mutex again.

```
Thread1                   Thread2
{                         {
    lock(mutex);               lock(mutex);
    wait(mutex);               signal(mutex);
    unlock(mutex);             unlock(mutex);
}                          }
```

Say the three thread one statements are enclosed in a while(1) loop. Then assume that thread2 locks the mutex, signals it, and unlocks the mutex. and then doesn't end, but goes to sleep.

So will the value of the condition variable be changed permanently? If three statements of thread one are running in infinite lop, will it never wait and just find that the signal has been given? When wait call returns, does it set the value of the condition variable back to initial value?

If yes, can I use create,destroy or initialize methods on the variables to set the value back? If yes, how? What exactly do these functions do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_cond_signal()` will always wake at least one thread that is *currently* waiting on that condition variable in `pthread_cond_wait()`.  If the same thread or a different thread then calls `pthread_cond_wait()` again, it will block and wait for another signal.

This means that pthread condition variables must always be paired with some kind of shared data, protected by the mutex that is held when calling `pthread_cond_wait()`.  Before calling `pthread_cond_wait()`, the thread must check the shared data to see if the condition it wants to wait for has occurred - if not, it shouldn't wait.

The simplest example of such shared data might be a global flag.  In your example:

```
int flag = 0;

Thread 1 {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (!flag)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

Thread 2 {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    flag = 1;
    pthread_mutex_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

You can see here that when the condition is "reset" is entirely under your control - for example you could have `Thread 1` set `flag = 0;` before it calls `pthread_mutex_unlock()`.

The shared state is often more complex than a simple flag - for example you might have a producer thread call `pthread_mutex_wait()` while there is no room in a shared buffer.

Comment: In you rexample, after the 2nd thread 'signals', say some other statements were also written. After the signal given by thread 2, the thread1 wakes up and mutex is given to that thread1. does the 2nd thread go to sleep? and does it wake up (might or might not depending on who gets the mutex this time) after the mutex has been released?

Comment: 1) thread 1 acquires mutex. checks flag, flag is 0. enters while. wait statements unlocks mutex and does the thread go to sleep after that? if yes, whats the use of while loop? because when it wakes up it will only be after flag has been set to 1. An if statement could have made more sense. or if none of the statements is present, wait statements just unlcoks the mutex and waits for the signal. whats wrong>?

Comment: 2) thread 2 acquires mutex. sets flag as one and signals. (say the thread1 was in waiting state by now). So after signalling, does this thread2 now go to sleep? and does it wake up to fight for the mutex when mutex is released?

Comment: Also, Say I run the statements in thread2 again and again (in some sort of loop), the signal is given again and again. But there will be a time when thread1 has reached its wait statement. At that point of time, do previous signals affect this waiting or this waiting is totally from a different perspective? i.e., the next time signal is given by thread2, thread1 wakes up as if no signals were generated prior to it

Comment: @neeraj: The `pthread_cond_wait()` atomically unlocks the mutex and puts the process to sleep.  When Thread 2 signals the condition variable, Thread 1 will *not* wake up and continue until Thread 2 unlocks the mutex (`pthread_cond_signal()` does not block).  `pthread_cond_signal()` does nothing if no thread is waiting on the condition variable at that time (this is why you need to test the value of the flag before calling `pthread_cond_wait()`).

Comment: @neeraj:  A `while()` loop is used for two reasons: because `pthread_cond_wait()` can wake up spuriously; and because, depending on your logic, by the time it wakes up the flag may have been reset again by another thread.  It is good practice to *always* call `pthread_cond_wait()` within such a `while()` loop.

Comment: so after thread2 gives the signal, thread 2 will complete its execution, release its mutex but meanwhile a thread1 might have been selected which will wake up when the mutex is released by thread2?

Comment: @neeraj: Right - after Thread 2 call `pthread_cond_signal()`, Thread 1 is put into a state where it is waiting for the mutex to be unlocked (assuming Thread 1 was already waiting in `pthread_cond_wait()`).  Once the mutex has been unlocked, Thread 1 will be eligible to acquire the mutex and start running - at this point, it's equivalent to being blocked in a regular `pthread_mutex_lock()` on the mutex.

Comment: So, if another thread was waiting for the same signal, would it fight for the mutex? or the scheduler will decide which thread to wake up AFTER the mutex has been released or JUST AFTER the signal had been sent?